# imul using DWORD PTR [reg+reg*n-n]

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

I clearly don't understand what exactly is happening with this imul because when I do the calculations myself it does not come out as 2. If anyone could explain the r/m form and why imul is getting 2 I'd greatly appreciate it.

Both esi and ebx = 0x1.
The *4 is in reference to the word size, correct? (4 is DWORD I think)?
The last part, -0x4, is the displacement? Just for adding or subtracting from the value?

By the way, when I do the calculations myself I get -2 if you didn't already guess.

```
9: x/32xw $esp
0xffffd300: 0xffffd3f4  0x00000000  0xffffd338  0x08049226
0xffffd310: 0x00000001  0x00000002  0x00000006  0x00000001
0xffffd320: 0x00000002  0x00000006  0xffffd358  0x08048a83
0xffffd330: 0x0804b6d0  0x08049620  0xffffd358  0x08048a7a
8: /x $ebp = 0xffffd328
7: /x $ebx = 0x1
6: /x $ecx = 0x0
5: /x $edx = 0x0
4: /x $edi = 0x0
3: /x $esi = 0xffffd310
2: /x $eax = 0x2
1: x/10i $eip
=> 0x8048b79 <phase_2+49>:  imul   eax,DWORD PTR [esi+ebx*4-0x4]
   0x8048b7e <phase_2+54>:  cmp    DWORD PTR [esi+ebx*4],eax

(gdb) 
0x08048b7e in phase_2 ()
9: x/32xw $esp
0xffffd300: 0xffffd3f4  0x00000000  0xffffd338  0x08049226
0xffffd310: 0x00000001  0x00000002  0x00000006  0x00000001
0xffffd320: 0x00000002  0x00000006  0xffffd358  0x08048a83
0xffffd330: 0x0804b6d0  0x08049620  0xffffd358  0x08048a7a
8: /x $ebp = 0xffffd328
7: /x $ebx = 0x1
6: /x $ecx = 0x0
5: /x $edx = 0x0
4: /x $edi = 0x0
3: /x $esi = 0xffffd310
2: /x $eax = 0x2
1: x/10i $eip
=> 0x8048b7e <phase_2+54>:  cmp    DWORD PTR [esi+ebx*4],eax
   0x8048b81 <phase_2+57>:  je     0x8048b88 <phase_2+64>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imul eax,DWORD PTR [esi+ebx*4-0x4]` is equivalent to this expression in C-like pseudocode:

```
eax = eax * *(uint32_t *)((uint8_t *)esi + ebx*4 - 4)
```

Substituting your values:

```
eax = 2 * *(uint32_t *)((uint8_t *)0xffffd310 + 1*4 - 4)
eax = 2 * *(uint32_t *)0xffffd310
eax = 2 * 1
eax = 2
```

Similarly, the `cmp` instruction is comparing `eax` with `DWORD PTR [esi+ebx*4]`, something like:

```
eax == *(uint32_t *)((uint8_t *)esi + ebx * 4)
2 == *(uint32_t *)((uint8_t *)0xffffd310 + 1*4)
2 == *(uint32_t *)0xffffd314
2 == 2
```

And will result in a true comparison.

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down, I'm not familiar with uint32_t/uint8_t but I have an idea and I'll read up on them now.

Comment: Is there a better type I could use?  In this case I'm just trying to indicate 32-bit and 8-bit integer types.

Comment: I'm sure what you used is right, I'm still just a beginner here and don't know C as well as I should.

Comment: You might be well advised to try learning C before delving into assembly.

Answer (score 0):

$esi is not 0x1--it's 0xffffd310 which is an address on the stack.  DWORD PTR is reading the contents of a stack memory location and the expression in [] is the address calculation.

Comment: I meant that the address esi is pointing to is 0x1, isn't that what imul will use for it's calculation?